# Mojo::DOM - XPath - Question

Tags: perl, dom, xpath, mojo

Why did the [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aDOM) developers create their own [Selectors](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aDOM#SELECTORS) and not use the XPath syntax?

Comment: Looks like they opted for CSS ("All CSS3 selectors that make sense for a standalone parser are supported.") over XPath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They didn’t exactly. CSS syntax is much more natural to a lot of web developers and, despite xpath’s power, CSS is a better impedance match for HTML DOM. It’s one of the reasons [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has done so well for example.